# Transferring rails schema and migrations from one rails app to a new one

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I messed up pretty bad and created a rails application without the `test` directory on accident.  I now need to make a whole new rails application but I have put a substantial amount of work into this first one.  Is there a way that I can transfer my schema, migrations and any other database (postgres in this case) related things over to the new application with ease?

Answer (score 1):

You don't really need the migrations if the db is as you want it, you can run `rails db:schema:dump` if you want to generate `schema.rb` file. The model files can be safely copied to your new project.

You can also just create a new project and then copy that projects test folder into your old one.

Comment: Oh wow really I can just copy and paste the tests folder into my original project.  Brilliant thank you! For my own reference though, if I did a ```db:schema:dumb``` and then transferred that ```schema.rb``` file, the migration files would not matter correct, and I would be more or less good to go?

Comment: Migration files are just to simplify updating the schema during development, they really should not be kept about for long, this is a very common misunderstanding. https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html#schema-dumping-and-you

Comment: Okay I see.  From there then when I would want to run the tests that I have written would it just be a ```rake run tests```?  Because when I run ```rake run --tasks``` I do not see anything similar as an option.

Comment: There might be some missing pieces if you just copy the folder over, you might better of creating a new project and running schema dump and so on